# Livewire, modal is not shown, why?

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-livewire

muestramodal.blade.ph

```
<x-button.link wire:click="edit">Edit</x-button.link>
<x-modal.dialog wire:model="edit">
    <x-slot name="title">Edit transaction</x-slot>
    <x-slot name="content">Hola</x-slot>
    <x-slot name="footer">
      
    </x-slot>
</x-modal.dialog>
```

---

muestramodal.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Muestramodal extends Component
{
    public $showEditModal = false;

    public function edit()
    {
        $this->showEditModal = true;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.muestramodal');
    }
}
```

Why is not shown modal , with click event button???
Several hours trying to solve this problem.....
Please , can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have changed. But nothing happens:

Comment: <div>
    <x-button.link wire:click="edit">Edit</x-button.link>
    
    <x-modal.dialog wire:model="showEditModal">
        <x-slot name="title">Edit transaction</x-slot>
        <x-slot name="content">Hola</x-slot>
        <x-slot name="footer">
          <x-button.secondary>Cancel</x-button.primary>
          <x-button.primary>Save</x-button.primary>
        </x-slot>
    </x-modal.dialog>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

need to update your muestramodal.php and extends LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent;

```
 <?php

   namespace App\Http\Livewire;
 
   LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent;

   class Muestramodal extends ModalComponent
   {
    public $showEditModal = false;

    public function edit()
    {
        $this->showEditModal = true;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.muestramodal');
    }
}
```